# ExpandableListView collapsing all parent items

Tags: android

I need a clue how to collapse (or find IDs for) all parent items in ExpandableListView.

Thanks,

Aleksander

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
int count =  mListAdapter.getGroupCount();
for (int i = 0; i <count ; i++)
  mListView.collapseGroup(i);
```